# Proof verification: $p, p + 4, p + 14$ are primes. Find $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question asks me to find $p$ such that $p$, $p + 4$, $p + 14$ are primes. After ruling out $p = 2$ and checking for a few cases, I claimed that there doesn't exist such a $p > 3$, hence $p = 3$.

I started by assuming that $p + 4$ and  $p + 14$ are primes. As $p = 6k \pm 1$, we have $$p+4 = \begin{cases}6k - 1 + 4 = 6k + 3 \equiv 0 \bmod{3} \\ 6k + 1 + 4 = 6k + 5\end{cases}$$
Clearly, the first case is composite, hence the second case must be prime, which implies that $p$ is of the form $6k + 1$. Similarly, we have $$p+14 = \begin{cases}6k - 1 + 14 = 6k + 13 \\ 6k + 1 + 14 = 6k + 15 \equiv 0 \bmod{3}\end{cases}$$
Here, the second case is clearly composite, hence the first case must be prime, which implies that $p$ is of the form $6k - 1$. But we have a contradiction from the previous conclusion. Hence, our assumption is incorrect, and we have $p = 3$.

I feel like this proof was rather haphazard. The textbook solution uses residue families, but I wanted to know if this proof is valid as well, and how I could improve it.

Comment: Your argument is fine.  Perhaps it would look clearer if you just rephrased it $\pmod 3$.  If $p>3$ then of course $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3$, but either choice leads to the same contradiction you found.

Comment: i see, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Using the previous suggestion, you could simply write: if $p\equiv 1\mod{3}$, then $p+14\equiv 1+14\equiv 15\equiv 0\mod{3}$, while if $p\equiv 2\mod{3}$, then $p+4\equiv 2+4\equiv 6\equiv 0\mod{3}$. Therefore $p\equiv 0\mod{3}$ and it follows that $p$ is prime.

Comment: Case checking like this is the intended purpose of this problem at this level. If are familiar with Fermat's little theorem, then you can be slick via mod $3$ like:
$$p(p+4)(p+14)\equiv p(p+1)(p-1)=p^3-p\equiv 0\bmod 3$$
so one of them must be divisible by $3.$

Comment: $p+14 = p + 2 + 12$ is divisible by 3 if and only if $p+2$ is. And it's rather obvious that at least one of $p, p+2, p+4$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: The (mod $3$) residues of $(p), (p+4),$ and $(p + 14)$ are all different, because none of the elements in the set $\{4,10,14\}$ is a multiple of $(3)$.  Therefore, exactly one of these three numbers must be a multiple of $(3)$.

Comment: Another way to see the same thing as in the previous comments: If $p\equiv a \bmod 3$, then $p+4\equiv a+1 \bmod 3$ and $p+14\equiv a+2 \bmod 3$. Among $a,a+1,a+2$ one of the residues must be $\equiv 0 \bmod 3$.

Comment: Well, *technically* your proof is slightly incomplete because it doesn't say why one of $p+4$ or $p+14$ cannot be $3$. Which is trivial if we are working in $\mathbb N$, so I am obviously nitpicking. (Otherwise, your proof is good!) However, if you are allowed to use negative numbers, then $p=-11, p+4=-7, p+14=3$ is also a solution, as is $p=-7, p+4=-3, p+14=7$ and $p=-17, p+4=-13, p+14=-3$.

Comment: @dezdichado that is indeed quite slick. thanks everyone else for your suggestions as well.

Comment: @StinkingBishop i am very uncomfortable with negative primes. are they actually fine mathematically?